# copy and paste based on certain conditions

Tags: excel, vba

i need a simple vba code. I hope someone can help me.
So, I want to copy the range B2:E6 and leave some cells marked with a special condition. I created a rule in cells A2:A6 with the value Y / X. In the end, I want to paste the value B2:E6 in the range F9:I13 only if the value is Y.

I am attaching the following image to make it easier for you to understand.

[image]

Any help will be great. And sorry my english is bad.

Comment: thank you. I've edited my post, please check again

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. You are expected to make your own research, attempt it first then ask a specific question about your code when you are stuck. Please edit your question and include your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend that you first define your working worksheet, if the CommandButton1 button code linked to the CommandButton1_Click() event, showen in your code, is not associated with your working sheet (Sheet9). Otherwise, the code will be executed on another Sheet than Sheet9, on which you want the conditions to be fulfilled.

So, I suggest this code, that formats also the target table "(F8:I13)":

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 Dim myWorkingSheet As Worksheet
 Dim Working_Range As Range, Target_Range As Range
 Dim Line_to_Read As Double, Table_Shift As Double

 Set myWorkingSheet = Sheets("Sheet9")
 myWorkingSheet.Activate
'    Copy the header table
 myWorkingSheet.Range("B1:E1").Copy Range("F8")
 Application.CutCopyMode = False
'    Copy the format of the table
 myWorkingSheet.Range("B1:E6").Copy
 myWorkingSheet.Range("F8").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
 Application.CutCopyMode = False

'  Copy table if current cell in column A = "y"
 Set Working_Range = myWorkingSheet.Range("A2:A6")
 Line_to_Read = 2
 Table_Shift = 7 'To start at F9 cell
 For Each wr In Working_Range
    If wr = "y" Then
        myWorkingSheet.Range(Cells(Line_to_Read, 2), Cells(Line_to_Read, 5)).Copy myWorkingSheet.Range(Cells(Line_to_Read + Table_Shift, 6), Cells(Line_to_Read + Table_Shift, 10))
    End If
    Line_to_Read = Line_to_Read + 1
 Next
 ' To point the cursor at the first cell.
 myWorkingSheet.Cells(1, 1).Select
End Sub
```

To avoid the repetition of myWorkingSheet in the you use With clause and End With.

Comment: Assalamolaiakom. hi mohamad, thanks for your help. I am totally newbie in macro code. I'm trying to understand the code you provided, but I can't. The example I was thinking of in the question is actually different to the worksheet I have. So, in my worksheet (A2:A6) is located at (A10:79) then the range to copy (B2:B6) is located at (AS10:DB79). The range to be pasted (F9:I13) is located at (DE89:FN158). I've tried to apply the code sample you provided but I'm still failing. I hope you will help me again. thank you

Comment: Wa alaykoum salam, #Pulung Udara Manggiling, So, you will replace myWorkingSheet.Range("A2:A6") by myWorkingSheet.Range("A10:A79"), put the values of Line_to_Read to (Line_to_Read = 9) and Table_Shift = 79, and the line under 'If wr = "y" Then' by (myWorkingSheet.Range(Cells(Line_to_Read, 45), Cells(Line_to_Read, 106)).Copy myWorkingSheet.Range(Cells(Line_to_Read + Table_Shift, 109), Cells(Line_to_Read + Table_Shift, 170)) ).

Comment: Thanks brother. I have followed your suggestion and It almost works perfectly. Just like the example above, I have table data in my worksheet that totals 70 rows with a table header above it. The first table was successfully copied and placed in the second table starting with the table header in cell (DE88:FN88) and followed by row number 1:70. When I specify the value "x" at number 1 in the table, it shouldn't be copied too, but it gets copied anyway. It also happens in line number 2.

Comment: It just starts when I specify the value "x" in line number 3 and so on, but the macro always executes one line above it. That is, for example if I specify the value "x" in row 3 then it will be placed in row number 2 in the second table. Another thing is, wherever the "x" value is placed, the last row (number 70) is not copied. Do you have another solution?

Comment: I just changed your code in this section Line_to_Read to (Line_to_Read = 9) to Line_to_Read to (Line_to_Read = 10). It actually solves almost all problems, except for one, which is that the first row remains copied, even though the value "x" is placed in the first table. Apart from that, everything went well. thanks mohamad.

Comment: Sorry that your problem is not completely resolved. I tell you that I can no longer follow, there is a gap between the problem posed initially and the one that corresponds to what you want :) :)  
Try to debug the code, and only test the first 2-3 lines to see why, the code doesn't interpret the "x" value correctly.  Good job.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can get you started

```
Sub Macro1()
Dest = 8
For Row = 1 To 6
    If Cells(Row, 1) <> "x" Then
        Range(Cells(Row, 2), Cells(Row, 5)).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Cells(Dest, 6).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    End If
    Dest = Dest + 1
Next Row
End Sub
```